# UItextfield initialized with empty string? not null? nor nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ternary-operator

i have a uitextfield, when it is initialized and i didn't input any values into it,  i found the value of the uitextfield is not null nor nil.

```
 NSString *notes = (notesField.text)?(notesField.text):@"hello";
    NSLog(@"notes: %@",notes);
```

it returns nothing for notes

```
    NSString *notes1;

//or use legnth

    if ([notesField.text isEqual:@""]) {
     notes1=@"hello";
        NSLog(@"empty textfield: %@",notes1);
        //then it returns "hello"
    }
    else
    {
        notes1=notesField.text;
        NSLog(@"not empty textfield: %@",notes1);
    }
```

Why is that? Can I still user ternary operator ?
like this ?

```
NSString *notes = ([notesField.text length])?(notesField.text):@"hello";
```

Comment: See my edited answer, hope that will make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
NSString *notes = ([notesField.text length])?(notesField.text):@"hello";
```

OR

```
NSString *notes = ([notesField.text length]==0)?@"hello":(notesField.text);
```

OR

```
NSString *notes = ([notesField.text isEqualToString:@""])?@"hello":(notesField.text);
```

And for the case when your `UITextField` has no entry (initial case), use the second or third option , that will be beter. `NSString *notes = ([notesField.text length])?@"hello":(notesField.text);` won't work fine as you expect because `notesField.text` will be `TRUE` even if there is no text in textfield. So you should use `notesField.text.length` or `[notesField.text isEqualToString:@""]`.

Hope its clear now.

Comment: shouldn't first one be :  NSString *notes = ([notesField.text length])?(notesField.text):@"hello";
when I run that, it returns me hello correctly.

Comment: yeah sure, my bad, didn't check the content, just meant to show you all posible options, see my edited answer, and if this helped you may please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The docs for [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) state

> **text**
>   The text displayed by the text field.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text
>   
>   **Discussion**
>   This string is @"" by default.

Note: if compiling under Xcode 5.02 or 5.1 and running in iOS earlier than iOS7, UITextField.text is initialised to nil. If running in iOS7+ it is initialised to @"".

If compiling in Xcode 4.6.3 or earlier then UITextField.text has (always) been initialised to @"", as per the documentation.

Radar bug: 16336863

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` must be initializing itself with a non-nil empty string. In situations where you don't care if the string is empty or nil, you can simply check the `length` property:

```
if (!notesField.text.length) {
    // text is nil or empty
}
```

Or using the ternary operator:

```
NSString *s = notesField.text.length ? notesField.text : @"Default";
```

This works because sending the `-length` selector to a nil object will return a default value of 0.

Answer (score -2):

That approach will work just fine.

As for why it's an empty string instead of nil, it's generally bad practice to return nil for something unless you want to indicate an error or an uninitialized state. An empty text field has a value. It's just an empty string.

Comment: Not always the case and in actual fact the docs for [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW2) state that the default value is `nil`

Comment: Also note that user may enter a bunch of spaces, which will make length of string non-zero, but still will not have any useful text. You need to trim the string before using using its length.

Comment: Ah, so they do. I missed that. I was taught to avoid nil / null in cases like this. Maybe I'm just old-fashioned.

Comment: @Paul.s: in actual fact the docs for UITextField state that the default value for text is @"", not nil. The text member is what the OP was concerned about.

Comment: @ghr the documentation seems to have changed. I've still got a version of the 6.1 doc set hanging around and it was `nil` then but in 7 it is now `@""`

Comment: @Paul.s: Interesting. My version of the 6.1 doc set says the default is @"" **but** my version of 6.0 doc set says the default is nil. My version of iOS 5.0 documentation says the default is @"". The behaviour of an app of mine since iOS 4 is that the default is @"". I've just discovered that Xcode5 has broken this when running on iOS < 7.

Comment: Correction: My version of iOS 5.1 documentation says the default is nil.